# Test multiple algorithms in one experiment

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

Is there any way to test multiple algorithms rather than doing it once for each and every algorithm; then checking the result? There are a lot of times where I don’t really know which one to use, so I would like to test multiple and get the result (error rate) fairly quick in Azure Machine Learning Studio.

Comment: you'll get your question flagged as 'too broad'...consider asking more specific question.....If you are into artificial intelligence consider following AI stack exchange http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481/artificial-intelligence?referrer=ZmhvdPpNkK4uGj6x_HIV1w2 hit the commit button on that page

Comment: I don't think that question is too broad - this is a common problem in machine learning that in order to find good model you need to check several different algorithms. To compare them you can use CV as Anders Gill pointed. You can also look into automatic ML solutions that will check several models for you. There is a library called auto-sklearn for example https://github.com/automl/auto-sklearn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module you are looking for, is the one called “**Cross-Validate Model**”. It basically splits whatever comes in from the input-port (dataset) into 10 pieces, then reserves the last piece as the “answer”; and trains the nine other subset models and returns a set of accuracy statistics measured towards the last subset. What you would look at is the column called “Mean absolute error” which is the average error for the trained models. You can connect whatever algorithm you want to one of the ports, and subsequently you will receive the result for that algorithm in particular after you “right-click” the port which gives the score.

After that you can assess which algorithm did the best. And as a pro-tip; you could use the **Filter-based-feature selection** to actually see which column had a significant impact on the result.

Answer (score 2):

You could connect the scores of multiple algorithms with an 'Evaluate Model' button to evaluate algorithms against each other. 
Hope this helps.

[image: Azure ML Canvas for an ensemble evaluation]

[image: Results of Evaluate Model module]

Answer (score 0):

You can check section 6.2.4 of hands-on-lab at GitHub https://github.com/Azure-Readiness/hol-azure-machine-learning/blob/master/006-lab-model-evaluation.md which focuses on the evaluation of multiple algorithms etc.